# Get Active or Default Sheet using ExcelDataReader

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader

How can I get content of the Active sheet or the default sheet of an .xlsx workbook? I have to read many workbooks and I do not know the name of the Active sheets.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open("C:\\test\\test.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);

excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

while (excelReader.Read()) {
    Console.WriteLine(excelReader.GetString(0));
}
```

I know how to do it using OfficeOpenXml but ExcelDataReader is lightweight and AsDataSet makes it very easy to turn excel data into JSON.

```
Using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage()) {
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                 pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault(f => f.View.TabSelected);

            string ActiveSheetName =  ws.Name;
   }
```

Any help here is highly appreciated!

Comment: ExcelDataReader does not support getting the Active sheet (currently, per May 2020)

Comment: You really, really don't want to...  "Active" or "Selected" is one of the biggest causes for errors as often it's difficult to anticipate it and handle all possible errors.  Especially when user interaction is involved.